# Return the same raw value for unknown enum

Tags: ios, swift, enums, swift3

I would like return the same value for the unknown enum,

I having the below enums defined in my code,

```
public enum Airport: String {
    case munich = "MUN_T01"
    case sanFrancisco = "SANF_T02"
    case singapore = "SP_T03"

   public var name: String {
        switch self {
        case .munich:
            return "Munich"
        case .sanFrancisco:
            return "San Francisco"
        case .singapore:
            return "Singapore"
   }
}
```

Whenever I call the above enum, it works fine

```
var airportName = Airport(rawValue: "MUN_T01")
print("Airport Name: ", airportName)   // munich
print("Airport Code: ", airportName.rawValue)   // MUN_T01
```

Now I want to cover the same for other/unknown scenarios, for eg.,

`var unknownAirportName = Airport(rawValue: "Test_T01")`,

should print `unknown` or `other` when I print `unknownAirportName` variable and

if I print `unknownAirportName.rawValue`, it should print `Test_T01`

I was able to get until other/unknown case but I couldn't get to print the same value (Test_T01) that is passed. Any help?

Comment: `Airport(rawValue: "Test_T01")` should generate a `nil` item, as it's not possible for the "default code" to parse the result.  Instead, you'd need to provide your own parser code so that if you can't find a match for specified text, you can return a `unknown` result

Comment: You could also make a case for the other scenario like `case other = "Other"` and then do something like this `var unknownAirportName = Airport(rawValue: "Test_T01") ?? Airport.other`

Answer (score 0):

Consider replacing enum with raw values to enum with associated ones and then you can make known and unknown cases, for instance:

```swift
public enum Airport {
    case airport(name: String, code: String)
    case unknown(code: String)
    
    static let airports = [
        Self.airport(name: "Munich", code: "MUN_T01"),
        Self.airport(name: "San Francisco", code: "SANF_T02"),
        Self.airport(name: "Singapore", code: "SP_T03")
    ]
    
    var name: String {
        if case let .airport(name, _) = self {
            return name
        }
        return "Unknown"
    }
    
    var code: String {
        switch self {
            case let .airport(_, code):
                return code
            case let .unknown(code):
                return code
        }
    }
    
    static func airport(code: String) -> Airport {
        if let item = Self.airports.first(where: { $0.code == code }) {
            return item
        }
        return unknown(code: code)
    }
}

let airport = Airport.airport(code: "MUN_T01")
print("Airport:", airport.name, airport.code) // Airport: Munich MUN_T01

let airport2 = Airport.airport(code: "NONE")
print("Airport:", airport2.name, airport2.code) // Airport: Unknown NONE
```